# Was there a belief that the poor could steal thoughts from people's minds?

Tags: victorian

[The Portal Wiki's list of Fact Sphere's Partially True Facts](https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/List_of_Fact_Sphere_facts#Partially_True_Facts)...

> In Victorian England, a commoner was not allowed to look directly at the Queen, due to a belief at the time that the poor had the ability to steal thoughts.

Is it true Victorians *believed* the poor could steal thoughts?

Comment: The bold text leads me to be skeptical about the authority/veracity of the rest of the text.

Comment: I'm flagging this post as space because it's space. Spaaaaaace!

Comment: The Victorians had all sorts of weird beliefs and social mores, especially about class and women. I think people are getting hung up on the context.